# Remove null element from mongo array

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

```
{
        "_id" : 160,
        "info" : [
            {
                'name': 'Serg',
                'proff': 'hacker'
            },
            null,
        ]
    }
```

As you can see I have null element in my array, I need a general solution that will remove null elements from info array.

I tried this:

```
for doc in iter:
    people.update({ '_id' : doc['_id']}, { '$pull' : { 'info' : 'null' }})
```

where `iter` is a collection of documents. and `people` is a collection

I also tried this in the shell:

```
> db.people.findAndModify({ query: {}, update: {'$pull': {info:null} } } )
```

But none of the above examples delete this null from my documents!! ))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work out for you. In python null is called None.

```
    for doc in iter:
        people.update({'_id':doc[id]},{'$pull':{'info':None}})
```

[null object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/nulls-object-in-python)

Also in mongo shell, this should work out:

```
    db.people.update({_id:160},{$pull:{info:null}})
```

If you want the update operator, to update more that one document at a time, that is to pull out null values from multiple documents, then you have to supply the multi:true option. Because by default, if the query arguemnt is left blank i.e. {} and mulit:true is not provided, update operator works on the first document that it finds

```
    db.people.update({},{$pull:{info:null}},{multi:true})
```