# Any way to tell whether a Python function returns a value

Tags: python

I am a newbie to Python. 
Here is a function, it could return a list of values or just return nothing in different occasions. How could I know which occasion the function runs.

I tried:

```
ans = foo()
if ans == null:
     # blablabla
```

But failed.

Comment: If a function does not explicitly return a value, it returns `None`.

Comment: @poorsod: maybe because anyone could do a web search to discover that Python does not have `null` but does have `None`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [null object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` does not exist in python. You should use `None` instead:

```
ans = foo()
if ans is None:
     # blablabla
```

More simply, you could just check if it is a truthy value. Keep in mind that an empty list is not.

```
ans = foo()
if ans:
     # blablabla
```

Comment: You might want to use `is None` here rather than `== None`.

Comment: `is None` ? `is` is a python keyword?

Comment: Yes. It tests if two references are to the same object.

Comment: @poorsod Python is awesome

Comment: @Wilbeibei: Have a look at PEP-8: "[Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)"