# Return `undefined` from Python function with PyV8?

Tags: javascript, python, undefined, v8, pyv8

I'm using PyV8 and I'd like to call a javascript function with `undefined`. It seems that evaluating both `undefined` and `null` return Python's `None` value:

```
>>> evaljs("undefined")
None
>>> evaljs("null")
None
```

The problem, of course, is that they're not the same in javascript:

```
>>> evaljs("undefined === null")
False
False
>>> evaljs("undefined") == evaljs("null")
None
None
True
```

Is there any nice way to go about doing this? I'd actually like to write a Python function, callable from javascript, which returns `undefined` in certain cases and `null` in other cases.

EDIT for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)-ness:

```
import PyV8

context = PyV8.JSContext()

def evaljs(s):
    with context:
        res = context.eval(s)
        print res
        return res
```

Comment: @bfavaretto: I meant that I'd like to write a Python function which returns `undefined` instead of `null`

Comment: I missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: in the current version there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here: [null object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python), there is no `null` or `undefined` in Python, just `None`... so you would only be able to represent `undefined` and `null` from JavaScript as `None` in Python.  JavaScript makes a distinction between the two for its own reasons and, as far as I can tell from my own experiences, "undefined" is fairly unique to JavaScript.

The only thing I can think of would be to get down into the source and see how undefined and null are being tracked in the JavaScript v8 engine and trying to have that object return when you evaluate JavaScript statements with null or undefined results... but that's quite the daunting task.