# Understanding the use of d[key] = None

Tags: python, dictionary

Learning some python by reading some code and trying to understand the usage of None on the dictionary's. Could you please bring some more light on the following snippet. and the usage of the  = None .

```
for pc in csv_dict:
        if pc in shp_dict:
            matched[pc] = None
        else:
            csv_not_in_shp[pc] = None
```

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the context. It can mean anything, it can mean nothing.

Comment: I think this particular use of `None` stems from a lack of understanding of sets. It looks very much like the original author actually wants `matched = {pc for pc in csv_dict if pc not in shp_dict}`. Detailed in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right to be confused, because this doesn't strike me as the finest example of Python coding. Just looking at the identifier names, we can sort of see the author's intent:

```
for pc in csv_dict:
    if pc in shp_dict:
        matched[pc] = None
    else:
        csv_not_in_shp[pc] = None
```

So here we have a `csv_dict` and `shp_dict` coming in, and we're writing out to two more dicts called `matched` or `csv_not_in_shp`. Clearly what this is setting up for later is a similar kind of test where the author can see:

```
if thing in matched:
    # it was in both csv_dict and shp_dict earlier
elif thing in csv_not_in_shp:
    # it wasn't so do something else
```

When you break it down like this, you can already start to see the problems. For instance, why do we need `elif` here? That could easily be rewritten:

```
if thing in matched:
    # it was in both csv_dict and shp_dict earlier
else:
    # it wasn't so do something else
```

This (probably correctly) suggests that `csv_not_in_shp` isn't necessary at all.

But let's give the original author the benefit of the doubt. Maybe `csv_dict` and `shp_dict` won't be around at the time of this comparison. (Pretty weak reason since they could have been passed from presumably the same place `matched` and `csv_not_in_shp` were, but...) The **real** problem here is that the author is using `None` for the value because **he doesn't care what the value is**. In other words, he's very much using it as a `NULL` placeholder.

The problem is, this is because **he's not mapping a key to a value**. The author is overlooking a clear use case for **sets**. Observe:

```
matched = set()
for pc in csv_dict:
    if pc in shp_dict:
        matched.add(pc)
```

Now we are saying what we really mean. Here's a basic example illustrating the concept. Let `d` be a dict mapping the letters 'a' to 'e' to the numbers 0 through 4, and `d_` be a dict mapping 'd' to 'g' to the numbers 3 through 6. (I will use `OrderedDicts` below so the keys are presented in a more readable format. They are otherwise unnecessary.)

```
>>> import string
>>> from collections import OrderedDict as od
>>> d = od([(k,v) for k, v in zip(string.ascii_lowercase[:5], range(5))])
>>> d_ = od([(k,v) for k, v in zip(string.ascii_lowercase[3:7], range(3,7))])
>>> d
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4)])
>>> d_
OrderedDict([('d', 3), ('e', 4), ('f', 5), ('g', 6)])
>>> matched = set()
>>> for key in d:
...   if key in d_:
...     matched.add(key)
... 
>>> matched
{'e', 'd'}
```

With a set, we can still do `in` matching, which is all we wanted in the first place:

```
>>> 'a' in matched
False
>>> 'd' in matched
True
```

And the best thing, of course, is that the whole thing can be reduced down to a set comprehension:

```
>>> {key for key in d if key in d_}
{'e', 'd'}
```

So `matched = {pc for pc in csv_dict if pc in shp_dict}` would more correctly replace your original code with a set, following my example.

Comment: excellent thank you so much ... lots of learning .. how about memory usage with sets ? should i worry about it ?

Comment: I doubt it. Like any other built-in Python data type, I'm sure they're heavily optimized. Of course, very large ones may get clunky, but you're going to get that with a dict or a list.

Answer (score 1):

`None` is similar to `null` (with [subtle differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python#comment24677338_3289606)) in other programming languages. In this case, it is being used to indicate that the key `pc` does not currently have a value. Therefore, when you try to access it, instead of giving you a KeyError, it will simply return `None`.

`None` can also be used in `if` statements to check for existence:

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = 5

>>> if a:
...     print 'a Exists'
>>> if b:
...     print 'b Exists'
...
b Exists
```

In this case above, the `if` statement checks to see whether a value exists and is not `None`.

Something closer to your example:

```
>>> a = [None,None,1,2.234,'d',None]
>>> for i,item in enumerate(a):
...     if item:
...         print i, item
...
2 1
3 2.234
4 d
```

Here is a [Useful Reference](http://www.pythoncentral.io/python-null-equivalent-none/)

Comment: I wouldn't say `None` is equivalent to `null`, there are subtle differences.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what these differences are, or reference something which does?

Comment: @Zirak, Done. I have added link in the first line.

Comment: See my answer. I think this is a bad use of `None` precisely because it _is_ used as a `NULL` placeholder, somewhat incorrectly IMO.