# How to "test" NoneType in python?

Tags: python, nonetype

I have a method that sometimes returns a NoneType value. So how can I question a variable that is a NoneType? I need to use ***if*** method, for example

```
if not new:
    new = '#'
```

I know that is the wrong way and I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: I think this was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or) and apparently somewhere before

Comment: If `None` is the only value your method returns for which `bool(returnValue)` equals `False`, then `if not new:` ought to work fine. This occurs sometimes in the built-in libs - for example, [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) returns either None or a truthy match object.

Comment: Also see my answer about `null` and `None` in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python/48504780#48504780).

Answer (score 999, accepted):

> So how can I question a variable that is a NoneType?

Use `is` operator, like this

```
if variable is None:
```

**Why this works?**

Since [`None`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) is the sole singleton object of [`NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType) in Python, we can use `is` operator to check if a variable has `None` in it or not.

Quoting from [`is` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is),

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

Since there can be only one instance of `None`, `is` would be the preferred way to check `None`.

---

**Hear it from the horse's mouth**

Quoting [Python's Coding Style Guidelines - PEP-008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) (jointly defined by Guido himself),

> Comparisons to singletons like **`None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`**, **never the equality operators**.

Comment: So what's the difference between `== None` and `is None`?

Comment: @NoName With respect to `None`, they both will yield similar result.

Comment: this doesn't work if comparing whether a `pandas` DataFrame exists -- for that, I use ``type(df) is type(None)`` to avoid: `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous`

Comment: @NoName See [Python None comparison: should I use “is” or ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14247373/4518341)

Comment: `isinstance(instance, type(None))` should be added to make this a complete answer. There are edge cases. For example, if you are building a dynamic tuple of types for validation and the validator is using isinstance (which takes a tuple).

Comment: @Rafe None is specific but it's not rare. If you don't expect a value such as None in your validation solution, you really are seeking trouble. A simple lambda will do the job: `isinstance_or_none = lambda x, t: x is None or isinstance(x, t)`

Comment: Can we do: `if not variable:`?

Comment: This does not work for me. When I enter: 

if variable is None

I get the error: NameError: name 'variable' is not defined

This does work, is there anything better?:

'''try:
    if variable is None:
        pass
except:
    variable = 10
print (variable)'''

Answer (score 137):

```
if variable is None:
   ...
```

---

```
if variable is not None:
   ...
```

Comment: Wrong.  If not variable is None:

Answer (score 72):

It can also be done with `isinstance` as per [Alex Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40553322/4288043) :

```
>>> NoneType = type(None)
>>> x = None
>>> type(x) == NoneType
True
>>> isinstance(x, NoneType)
True
```

`isinstance` is also intuitive but there is the complication that it requires the line

`NoneType = type(None)`

which isn't needed for types like `int` and `float`.

Comment: Since you can't subclass `NoneType` and since `None` is a singleton, `isinstance` should not be used to detect `None` - instead you should do as the accepted answer says, and use `is None` or `is not None`.

Comment: There are edge cases. For example, if you are building a dynamic list of types for validation and the validator is using `isinstance` (which takes a list).

Comment: Correction: tuple, not list

Comment: Also, `assert isinstance(x, str) or x is None` will not result in `x` being inferred as `str | None` by Pyright, but `assert isinstance(x, (str, type(None)))` will.

Comment: Given that current [doc of isinstance](https://web.archive.org/web/20230822114519/https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) says nothing about this case I suppose this is valid Python code. However if you use **mypy** be aware of this currently-open [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13154).

Answer (score 36):

***As pointed out by Aaron Hall's comment:***

> Since you can't subclass `NoneType` and since `None` is a singleton, `isinstance` should not be used to detect `None` - instead you should do as the accepted answer says, and use `is None` or `is not None`.

---

***Original Answer:***

The simplest way however, without the extra line in addition to [cardamom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086383/how-to-test-nonetype-in-python/48464170#48464170) is probably:
`isinstance(x, type(None))`

> So how can I question a variable that is a NoneType? I need to use if method

Using `isinstance()` does not require an `is` within the `if`-statement:

```
if isinstance(x, type(None)): 
    #do stuff
```

---

**Additional information**
You can also check for multiple types in one `isinstance()` statement as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). Just write the types as a tuple.

```
isinstance(x, (type(None), bytes))
```

Comment: Since you can't subclass `NoneType` and since `None` is a singleton, `isinstance` should not be used to detect `None` - instead you should do as the accepted answer says, and use `is None` or `is not None`.

Comment: @AaronHall Why `isinstance` **should not** be used ? I understand that `is` should be preferred, but there are some cases where the isinstance form feels more natural (like checking for multiple types at once `isinstance(x, (str, bool, int, type(None)))`).
Is it just a personal preference or is there caveat that I'm unaware of ?

Comment: @Conchylicultor downsides to your suggestion: 1. global look-up for `type` 2. then calling it 3. then looking up the type of `None` - when `None` is both a singleton and a keyword. Another downside: 4. this is very non-standard and will raise eyebrows when people are looking at your code. `x is None` is a more optimized check. I would suggest `x is None or isinstance(x, (str, bool, int))` - but I would also suggest you think more about what you're doing when you're doing that kind of type checking for types that don't have a lot in common...

Answer (score 19):

Not sure if this answers the question. But I know this took me a while to figure out. I was looping through a website and all of sudden the name of the authors weren't there anymore. So needed a check statement.

```
if type(author) == type(None):
     print("my if body")
else:
     print(" my else body")
```

Author can be any variable in this case, and `None` can be any type that you are checking for.

Comment: Since `None` is a singleton, `type` should not be used to detect `None` - instead you should do as the accepted answer says, and use `is None` or `is not None`.

Comment: WTH is `my else body`?!

Comment: @jtlz2 sorry I should have clarified. My else body is whatever code you want to happen if the else statement executes. Its not a protected python wording if you're wondering

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 :

```
x = None
isinstance(x, type(None))
```

or

```
isinstance(None, type(None))
```

==> True

Comment: Since you can't subclass `NoneType` and since `None` is a singleton, `isinstance` should not be used to detect `None` - instead you should do as the accepted answer says, and use `is None` or `is not None`.

Comment: How this is copied to every answer, nice --

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will be helpful for you)

```py
print(type(None))  # NoneType
```

So, you can check type of the variable name

```py
# Example
name = 12  # name = None

if type(name) is type(None):
    print("Can't find name")
else:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Because `None` is a singleton and `None` is the only instance of `NoneType`, your example is more complicated than necessary. Just check your variable for `None`: `if name is None: ...`

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use the following method to check for NoneType.

```
if (new): # not None
  ...
else: # NoneType
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test explicitly for `NoneType` by importing it:

```
>>> from types import NoneType
```

or, without import:

```
>>> NoneType = type(None)
```

When is this useful?

When you have a variable that's optional which can be either set to its type or to `None`. Now you want to validate its type using a single `isinstance` call:

```py
>>> from types import NoneType
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> assert isinstance(foo, (str, NoneType))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
>>> assert isinstance(foo, str) or isinstance(foo, NoneType)
```

as well as:

```
>>> assert isinstance(foo, str) or (foo is None)
```