# Check if return value is instance of Py_None

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api

I have to use a [c](/questions/tagged/c) function (`myAPI.readArr`) that returns a scalar,`numpy.ndarray` or `Py_None` on failure.

This works for a failure:

```
data = myAPI.readArr(arg1, arg2)
if not data:
   raise Exception("Problem!")
```

but for valid arguments I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I check that the call succeeded or not?

Comment: PEP 8 explicitly recommends testing `is None` when you mean `is None`, in part because many objects besides `None` are falsey—like, say, `False`. The fact that some objects are illegal to test for falsiness, like NumPy arrays, just means that you get an early error message for your mistake instead of code that seems to work until you deploy it and it silently screws up your data. :)

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or) is the canonical answer, but the linked one seems to more directly answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = myAPI.readArr(arg1, arg2)
if data is None:
   raise Exception("Problem!")
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086405/471899) contains more details about comparison to `None`

Answer (score 3):

```
if data is None:
    raise Exception("Problem!")
```

Testing `is None` is better because it returns `True` if and only if the value is `None`, not if it evaluates to zero.