# How to set default value for variable?

Tags: python, undefined

Imagine I have the following code in javascript

```js
function test(string) {
    var string = string || 'defaultValue'
}
```

What is the Python way of initiating a variable that may be undefined?

Comment: The answers tell you how to have a parameter with a default value, but maybe you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086383/how-to-test-nonetype-in-python

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the exact scenario you present, you can use default values for arguments, as other answers show.

Generically, you can use the `or` keyword in Python pretty similarly to the way you use `||` in JavaScript; if someone passes a falsey value (such as a null string or `None`) you can replace it with a default value like this:

```
string = string or "defaultValue"
```

This can be useful when your value comes from a file or user input:

```
string = raw_input("Proceed? [Yn] ")[:1].upper() or "Y"
```

Or when you want to use an empty container for a default value, which is problematic in regular Python (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)):

```
def calc(startval, sequence=None):
     sequence = sequence or []
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning, for `None` specifically, do `string = string if string is not None else "defaultValue"`. Reference: [How to "test" NoneType in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23086383/4518341)

Comment: I wouldn't use `sequence or`, cause it's too loose. For example, if I accidentally passed in the integer `0`, I'd expect a `TypeError`, but this'd silently use the default. This'd be better: `if sequence is None or len(sequence) == 0: sequence = []`. But thinking about that, why bother swapping out empty sequences? If you're actually intending to only replace `None`, do that explicitly instead of using `or`: `sequence = sequence if sequence is not None else []`.

Answer (score 6):

For a function parameter, you can use a **default argument value**:

```
def test(string="defaultValue"):
    print(string)

test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use default values:

```
def test(string="defaultValue")
    pass
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values