# Determining a variable's type is NoneType in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, nonetype

I would like to check if a variable is of the `NoneType` type. For other types we can do stuff like:

```
    type([])==list
```

But for `NoneType` this simple way is not possible. That is, we cannot say `type(None)==NoneType`. Is there an alternative way? And why is this possible for some types and not for others? Thank you.

Comment: Just use `x is None`. There is no advantage whatsoever to checking the type, as there will never under any circumstances be any object other than `None` of type `NoneType`.

Comment: I think the idea is to be able to pass `type(x) == y` for any x,y, not to add a special case for `x is None`. Note: you can also do `x == None`.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus see above in case you weren't notified.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`NoneType` just happens to not automatically be in the global scope. This isn't really a problem.

```
>>> NoneType = type(None)
>>> x = None
>>> type(x) == NoneType
True
>>> isinstance(x, NoneType)
True
```

In any case it would be unusual to do a type check. Rather you should test `x is None`.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose both this solution and the solution of @JeanFrancoisFabre do the job. Do we have some reason to prefer one of them over the other (speed,style,etc.)?

Comment: @splinter not that I know of.

Answer (score 17):

Of course you can do it.

```
type(None)==None.__class__

True
```