# Why does this lambda function always return False even when the type matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

Given:

```
type(m[11].value)
<class 'NoneType'>

type(m[12].value)
<class 'str'>
```

Why then does the following lambda function always return false when I pass it the two above vars?

```
g = lambda x: type(x) is None
```

Comment: `>>> type(None) is None` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Because `<class 'NoneType'>` is not the same object as `None`. `type(None)` is `<class 'NoneType'>`. But then you may as well just use `x is None`.

Comment: I was influenced by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086383/how-to-test-nonetype-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're checking whether the *type* of an object is `None`, and not the actual object itself. `type` returns a `type` object, the actual type/class of that object. In the particular case of `None`, it returns `NoneType`:

```
>>> type(None)
NoneType
```

Since object has a type, `type(x) is None` will never evaluate to `True`.

Why not just test the object *directly*? Additionally, if you are going to name a `lambda`, you may as well define your own function.

```
>>> def check(x):
...     return x is None
... 
>>> check(None)
True
```

Alternatively, you may use an `isinstance` check -

```
>>> isinstance(None, type(None))
True
```

As a side note, the [`pd.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) function from the `pandas` library provides this functionality directly.