# Use of isinstance(variable,data_type_name) function for NoneType data type gone wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, isinstance

Suppose a variable is defined:

```py
a=None
```

On running below code:

```py
print(isinstance(a,NoneType))
```

gave error: **NameError**: name 'NoneType' is not defined
For any other data type, its working correctly

```py
print(isinstance(5,int), isinstance(4.0,float), isinstance(False,bool), isinstance("on_and_on",str), isinstance([1,"2",3.0,True,None],list), isinstance((1,"2",3.0,True,None),tuple), isinstance({4,1,3,2},set), isinstance({1:"a","apple":2,5.0:True},dict), isinstance(5-2j,complex))
```

Why?

Comment: The issue isn't `isinstance` at all, that function never even gets called because there is a `NameError`, because `NoneType` is not a variable that is defined anywhere. The linked duplicate was bad, but this is definitely a duplicate. I've changed the target to a more appropriate duplicate

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare the type:

```py
isinstance(a, type(None))
### result:
True
```

or just use a bool check:

```py
a=None

if a is None:
    print("a is NoneType")

### result:
a is None type
```

see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086383/how-to-test-nonetype-in-python) if you're interested in some theory.