# How to ignore NoneType error in tweet ID statuses_lookup

Tags: json, python-3.x, tweepy

I am trying to collect tweets with tweepy from a list of tweet ids `good_tweet_ids_test`, using `statuses_lookup`.
Since the list is a bit old, some tweets will have been deleted by now. Therefore I ignore errors in the lookup_tweets function, so it does not stop each time.

Here is my code so far:

```
def lookup_tweets(tweet_IDs, api):
    full_tweets = []
    tweet_count = len(tweet_IDs)
    try:
        for i in range((tweet_count // 100) + 1):
            # Catch the last group if it is less than 100 tweets
            end_loc = min((i + 1) * 100, tweet_count)
            full_tweets.extend(
                api.statuses_lookup(tweet_IDs[i * 100:end_loc], tweet_mode='extended')
            )
        return full_tweets
    except:
        pass

results = lookup_tweets(good_tweet_ids_test, api)
temp = json.dumps([status._json for status in results]) #create JSON
newdf = pd.read_json(temp, orient='records')
newdf.to_json('tweepy_tweets.json')
```

But when I run the `temp = json.dumps([status._json for status in results])` line, it gives me the error:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

I do not know how to fix this. I believe the type of some of the statuses is None, because they have been deleted and can therefore not be looked up now. I simply wish for my code to move on to the next status, if the type is None.

EDIT: As have been pointed out, the issue is that `results` is `None`. So now I think I need to exclude `None` values from the `full_tweets` variable. But I cannot figure out how to. Any help?

EDIT2: With further testing I have found out that `results` is only `None` when there is a tweet ID that has now been deleted in the batch. If the batch contains only active tweets, it works. So I think I need to figure out how to have my function look up the batch of tweets, and only return those that are not `None`. Any help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "test" NoneType in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086383/how-to-test-nonetype-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for helping! I have tried this: `temp = json.dumps([status._json for status in results if status is not None])` based on that but it returns the same error. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @b4kke Is `results` `None`?

Comment: @Moosefeather Just checked, and yes, you are right, `results` is `None`. Guess there is something else wrong with my code then...

Comment: Ideas how to fix by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implicitly returning `None` when there's an error, you could explicitly return an empty list. That way, the result of `lookup_tweets` will always be iterable, and the calling code won't have to check its result:

```py
def lookup_tweets(tweet_IDs, api):
    full_tweets = []
    tweet_count = len(tweet_IDs)
    try:
        for i in range((tweet_count // 100) + 1):
            # Catch the last group if it is less than 100 tweets
            end_loc = min((i + 1) * 100, tweet_count)
            full_tweets.extend(
                api.statuses_lookup(tweet_IDs[i * 100:end_loc], tweet_mode='extended')
            )
        return full_tweets
    except:
        return [] # Here!
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I added your suggestion. Now `results` is not `NoneType`, but instead only returns ```[]``` when printed. Is it supposed to be extended to the list instead, or?