# How to skip over any value that is not in a range in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create 3 nested for loops and skip over any values that is not in any of the for loops. I have tried different ways but have not had much success yet. Here is the for loops:

```
for industry in string.ascii_uppercase:
    for code in range(1, 99):
        for year in range(1998, 2019):
            createCSV(industry, code, year)
```

the problem is there are industry and code values for which data is not available. The code breaks at code=3 because 3 is missing in the original values for the variable code. If it was only one value I could just skip it using continue.

```
for industry in string.ascii_uppercase:
for code in range(1, 99):
    if code == 3:
        continue
    for year in range(1998, 2019):
        createCSV(industry, code, year)
```

But there more missing values for both industry and code and I am trying to find an efficient way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably want a `try` and `except` statement.

Comment: Sounds like you clearly know what values are invalid so why not just store them in a `set` and then check containment while looping?

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which values are valid/invalid?

Comment: @pstatix and Carciagenicate I do not know what values are missing but I can figure that out. however, it would take time and the missing list would be too long so i am looking for a more efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way could be with a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) clause:

```
for industry in string.ascii_uppercase:
    for code in range(1, 99):
        for year in range(1998, 2019):
            try:
                createCSV(industry, code, year)
            except Exception:
                print(f"Warning: unable to create CSV for industry '{industry}' for code '{code}' for year '{year}'")
```

in which you can still replace the generic `Exception` with the specific exception class that your `createCSV` function raises. If you know for example that `createCSV` will raise a `ValueError` when an invalid `code` value is provided as input argument, then replace `except Exception:` with `except ValueError:`. This will help avoid some potential pitfalls (see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51) for more info).

However if at all possible I would recommend to instead:

- Retrieve an iterable with only the valid `code`values beforehand and then only loop over these, OR
- Modify the programming code of `createCSV` such that it doesn't break when an invalid `code` value is provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know which values causes error then avoid looping over them.

```
missing_code_values=[3,4,5,6,7,83]
missing_ascii_values=['A','Z']
for industry in [x for x in string.ascii_uppercase if x not in missing_ascii_values]:
    for code in [x for x in range(1, 99) if x not in missing_code_values]:
        for year in range(1998, 2019):
            createCSV(industry, code, year)
```

If you don't know it, then you can use try/except

```
for industry in string.ascii_uppercase:
    for code in range(1, 99):
        for year in range(1998, 2019):
            try:
                createCSV(industry, code, year)
            except: # mention specific exception if you can
                print("Skipping Industry-",industry," Code-",code," Year-",year)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can check against [Null in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python):

```
 for industry in string.ascii_uppercase:
 for code in range(1, 99):
   if code is None:
     continue
 for year in range(1998, 2019):
   createCSV(industry, code, year)
```

Comment: This won't work because `code` wont be `None` when iterating the range. The OP is stating that they know which values they need to skip, not test for nullness.