# Pandas - add a row at the end of a for loop iteration

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a for loop that gets a series of values and makes some tests:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['columnX','columnY', 'columnZ'])
for value in list:
    if value > 3:
       df['columnX']="A"
    else:
       df['columnX']="B"
       df['columnZ']="Another value only to be filled in this condition"
    df['columnY']=value-1
```

How can I do this and keep all the values in a single row for each loop iteration no matter what's the if outcome? Can I keep some columns empty?

I mean something like the following process:

```
[create empty row] -> [process] -> [fill column X] -> [process] -> [fill column Y if true] ...
```

Like:

```
[index columnX columnY columnZ]
[0        A       0      NULL ]
[1        A       1      NULL ]
[2        B       2     "..." ]
[3        B       3     "..." ]
[4        B       4     "..." ]
```

Comment: *keep all the values in a single row for each loop iteration* - what do you mean?

Comment: already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @Asif I'm getting: KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]' when attempting to "append" a new row in the fashion from the question you mentioned. What I want is more like: create emtpy row and fill the row according to a series of procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand exactly but I think this may be a solution:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d = {'columnX':[],'columnY':[]}
for value in list:
    if value > 3:
       d['columnX'].append("A")
    else:
       d['columnX'].append("B")
    d['columnY'].append(value-1)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

for the second question just add another condition

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d = {'columnX':[],'columnY':[], 'columnZ':[]}
for value in list:
    if value > 3:
       d['columnX'].append("A")
    else:
       d['columnX'].append("B")
    if condition:
        d['columnZ'].append(xxx)
    else:
        d['columnZ'].append(None)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Please, check my edits, I added another question related to "leaving empty columns".

Answer (score 0):

According to the example you have given I have changed your code a bit to achieve the result you shared:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['columnX','columnY', 'columnZ'])
for index, value in enumerate(list):
    temp = []
    if value > 3:
       #df['columnX']="A"
       temp.append("A")
       temp.append(None)
    else:
       #df['columnX']="B"
       temp.append("B")
       temp.append("Another value") # or you can add any conditions
    #df['columnY']=value-1
    temp.append(value-1)
    df.loc[index] = temp

print(df)
```

this produce the result:

```
  columnX        columnY  columnZ
0       B  Another value      0.0
1       B  Another value      1.0
2       B  Another value      2.0
3       A           None      3.0
4       A           None      4.0
5       A           None      5.0
```

df.index is printed as : Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')

Comment: So i'm forced to fill all the columns, even the ones that I have no value? Im asking this because in the original solution I have many columns and many of them will be empty.

Comment: None is equivalent to null / no value in python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You may just prepare/initialize your Dataframe with an *index* depending on input list size, then getting *power* from `np.where` routine:

```
In [111]: lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['columnX','columnY', 'columnZ'], index=range(len(lst)))

In [112]: int_arr = np.array(lst)

In [113]: df['columnX'] = np.where(int_arr > 3, 'A', 'B')

In [114]: df['columnZ'] = np.where(int_arr > 3, df['columnZ'], '...')

In [115]: df['columnY'] = int_arr - 1

In [116]: df
Out[116]: 
  columnX  columnY columnZ
0       B        0     ...
1       B        1     ...
2       B        2     ...
3       A        3     NaN
4       A        4     NaN
5       A        5     NaN
```