# Fields with NULL and blank values

Tags: python, django

I'm writing my first Python web application. My code is difficult because it often needs to treat fields separately if they contain a blank value `object.propery = ''` and a Null value `object.property = None`.

Is there a simple way of dealing with these two values as one? I've noticed some languages have a `isNullorEmpty()` function. I've also noticed that if a DB field is set to contain numbers then assigning a blank value to the field just makes it `Null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [null object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use

```py
if object.property:
    ....
```

This will work for empty strings and None.