# How to check in Python if a variable has been assigned or not

Tags: python

I would like to check, whether a variable has been assigned or not. Based on the answers in this question [Referring to the null object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/referring-to-the-null-object-in-python), I tried it with `if outputVariable==None` but this does not work and throws the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'outputVariable' referenced before assignment".

I have the following code:

```
def testMethod(assignVariable):
    if assignVariable == True:
        outputVariable = 5
        
    if outputVariable==None:
        outputVariable = 0
 
    return outputVariable


returnValue = testMethod(False)
```

Any idea how I can check before the return statement, if `outputVariable` has a value. If it does not, it should be given a value of 0

Update: Based on the accepted answer here [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists), I tried the following but it was also not successfull:

```
def testMethod(assignVariable):
    if assignVariable == True:
        outputVariable = 5
        
    if outputVariable in locals():
        pass
    else:
        outputVariable = 0       

    return outputVariable


returnValue = testMethod(False)
```

Comment: well, the error is referring to that if assignVariable is False, then outputVariable  is never assigned. So outputVariable  == None is checking towards something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: What error does the updated code give you?

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle: Thanks for the comment. The error message is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'outputVariable' referenced before assignment"

Comment: for that specific case, you need to use `if 'outputVariable' in locals()` with the 's, I also posted an answer that will hopefully help you as well

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been anwered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists).

If the variable has no value, it is non-existent because you cannot declare a variable without any sort of initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to help you:

```
def tryVar(var):
    try:
        val = var
    except NameError:
        return None
    return val
```

In your code, just use tryVar(--) wherever you want to get a variable, you can check if said variable exists by simply:

```
if tryVar(X) is None:
   >>>DO WHATEVER
```

Solution for python 3.8+ if you want to assign variable, and if it doesnt exist assign 0 to it in one line:

```
Z = x if tryVar(x) is None else x:=0
```

this assigns the variable if its not assigned, and returns its value, additionally if you don't want to do anything with the values you can also:

```
x if tryVar(x) is None else x:=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I acutally want is to check whether a variable exists. If it exists it should be returned, if not a value of 0 should be assigned to it and then it should be returned.

Comment: Thanks Zaid. Actually your comment from above helps me (while this answer does not really help me). I had to use the ' before the variable name

Comment: @PeterBe No worries, as long as your issue was resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't check for a variable that is not *defined*. Even `None` is a well-defined value for an object – it's a good default value in many scenarios.

This is the idiomatic way to achieve what you want:

```
def testMethod(assignVariable):

    return assignVariable or 0

returnValue = testMethod(False)
```

You can avoid that intermediate variable as it is not adding any value except being a placeholder; python takes care of all these checks internally. There is a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) also if you need one. Function is optional if it's for one-time use.

Comment: Thanks Nishant for your answer. Actually I have multiple variables that I want to return in my real application. How could I use your suggested appraoch with mutiple variables?

Comment: @PeterBe, You can have default values for each and then use the `or` like I said above. Please update the question with real example if you want me to update answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nishant. I could solve my issue by using the ' before the variable name of the variables in my updated question. But thanks anyways for your suggestion.